# Excel: Dynamically change chart calculation type based on what slicer value is selected

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

I have a dashboard which tracks different financials for the company. One of the charts on this dashboard shows the annual totals for whatever value that the user selects in a slicer.

The problem that I'm encountering is the chart always shows the `sum` of the values from each month, when sometimes `average` would be more appropriate.

Is there a way to have the chart update the calculation type based on what slicer is selected?

Here is the code (not working properly) (credit to @ARich) :

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetPivotTableUpdate(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    On Error GoTo err1
    Dim S   As Slicer
    Dim sI  As SlicerItem
    Dim PT  As PivotTable
'    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set S = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Type").Slicers("Type")

    For Each sI In S.SlicerCache.SlicerItems
        If sI.HasData And sI.Selected Then
            If sI.Caption = "Headcount" Then
                With Target.PivotFields("Sum of Value")
                        .Caption = "Average of Value"
                        .Function = xlAverage
                End With
                Exit For
            Else
                With Target.PivotFields("Average of Value")
                        .Caption = "Sum of Value"
                        .Function = xlSum
                End With
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
err1:
'    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In short: no. What you are looking for is an event that fires when you change from one slicer to another. But there is no event in Excel that captures the `selection` of a slicer or the `activation` thereof or any other usable event.

Yet, if you are willing to create your own slicer with a hovering form (modeless) then you would be able to capture that event.

Answer (score 1):

As Ralph mentioned, there's no slicer selection events. However, there are pivot table events, one of which is the [`PivotTable_Update` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822105.aspx). We can use this event to do what you're talking about:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetPivotTableUpdate(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    On Error GoTo err1
    Dim S   As Slicer
    Dim SI  As SlicerItem
    Dim PT  As PivotTable
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set S = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(1).Slicers("YourSlicer")

    For Each SI In S.SlicerCache.SlicerItems
        If SI.HasData And SI.Selected Then
            If SI.Caption = "Your Criteria" Then
                Target.PivotFields("YourField").Function = xlAverage
                Exit For
            Else
                Target.PivotFields("YourField").Function = xlSum
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
err1:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The way this works is that each time you make a slicer selection, the slicer filters the pivot table(s) it's connected to. The act of filtering a pivot is considered an update to the pivot, so the pivot table update event is fired.

This code would be placed in the `ThisWorkbook` module of your workbook. (There's also a worksheet specific version of this event called `Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate` which you would place in the sheet module of the sheet your pivot table is on. The rest of the code would remain the same.)

You'll have to make a few changes to the code to fit your workbook. For example, I don't know how many slicer caches you have in your workbook, the code above uses the first one. You'll also need to change `Slicer_Name` to the name of your slicer with the criteria you want to use. This code assumes that only one slicer selection would be enough to tell whether or not to use an average or sum, but you could modify it to require several selections before changing the calculation type.

Comment: For `Target.PivotFields("YourField")`, is that the name of the pivot table or chart or? It doesn't seem to be working for me when I use the table, chart or ActiveField name.

Comment: `Target` is the pivot table object that's passed as an argument to the procedure; it's the pivot that's being updated. `PivotFields("YourField")` is the field that you're averaging/summing.

Comment: I've tried a few different field names for `("YourField")`, but none seem to be working for me. Here's a screenshot of the fields: http://imgur.com/iaVhNJx

Comment: The field name refers to the actual field name, not the header value in the pivot. For example, if you pulled Revenues into the Values section of your pivot in order to perform an average, the field name would be "Revenues", not "Average of Revenues" or Average of Value". Try this: record a macro of you changing the sum on your pivot to an average then look at the recorded code. It will show you the field name.

Comment: Ahh, duh. Should've thought to try recording. However, when I did, I got `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pvtYearChart").PivotFields("Sum of Value")`. `Sum of Value` and `Value` didn't work....I wonder if I'm doing something else wrong. I'll edit the main post with my current code. I sincerely appreciate your help and patience

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot without additional information (e.g. what error are you seeing?). One issue that you might be encountering is if multiple pivots are connected to your slicers.

Comment: I'm not seeing an error per se, but rather nothing is happening when I change the slicer item. You are correct in that I have multiple pivots (3) connected to my slicers - what kind of issues could that cause?

Comment: @ARich I still can't get any event to fire. I tried all events before I posted my answer below. But none of the 17 possible events (for any given sheet) seem to fire merely by **selecting** the slicers I have in my sample Excel file. I have all events with a `Debug.Print "eventName just occurred"`. But nothing happens. What am I missing / doing wrong?

Comment: @Dr.Trey [Let's continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104195/room-for-arich-and-dr-trey).